# Is there any difference (performance) if I run ng-repeat over object or function that returns object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm binding an array in my service to the local scope in **controller** (pass by reference):

```
myApp.controller('TheController', function($scope, theService){
    $scope.theArray = theService.array;
})
```

**in Service**:

```
//...
theService.array = [];
    $http.get('/array').then(function(data){
        theService.array = angular.extends(theService.array, data);// here I'm updating theService.array with new values;
    })
```

Problem with that binding is that I can't *break* the reference to the initial array. so I have to make some extra function in order to detect what the diference between new and old array.

A work around would be to initialize the array every time and return a function in my **service**:

```
$http.get('/array').then(function(data){
        theService.array = data;
    })

theService.getArray = function(){
    return theService.array;
    };
```

in controller it would be:

```
myApp.controller('TheController', function($scope, theService){
        $scope.theArray = theService.getArray;
    })
```

in my **html** (and here is the question), I will have:

```
<div ng-repeat="data in theArray()">....</div>
```

instead of `<div ng-repeat="data in theArray ">....</div>`

Is there any problem concerning performance in ng-repeat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm concerned, in AngularJS' digest cycles all functions in the template is going to be called again (like what is happening when you put a function inside `ng-if`) and they may cause another digest cycles to be runned.

See [this](http://www.benlesh.com/2013/08/angularjs-watch-digest-and-apply-oh-my.html) and [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/) for further description, though they are not really talking about this matter particularly.

So I would rather run `ng-repeat` over the object and update the values occasionally when they really should be updated.